# How to call a dag task?

Tags: airflow, mwaa

I have two dags Dag 1 and Dag 2

task A, B and C are in a Dag 1
task D, E and F are in Dag 2

How to implement a third Dag to utilize the tasks?

I want Dag 3 to use task A, then task E and then task C without rewriting the functions

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that return an operator and reuse it from whatever DAG you need.

Example:

```
def create_my_opeartor(task_id=None, **kwargs):
    #Replace with your actual operator configuration
    return MyOperator(task_id=task_id, **kwargs) 

def create_my_opeartor_2(task_id=None, **kwargs):
    #Replace with your actual operator configuration
    return BashOperator(task_id=task_id, bash_command='echo "hello world", **kwargs)

with DAG(
    dag_id='DAG1',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2021, 8, 24),
) as dag1:
    a = create_my_opeartor(task_id='task_A')
    
with DAG(
    dag_id='DAG2',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2021, 8, 24),
) as dag2:
    e = create_my_opeartor_2(task_id='task_E')
    
with DAG(
    dag_id='DAG3',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=datetime(2021, 8, 24),
) as dag3:
    a = create_my_opeartor(task_id='task_A')
    e = create_my_opeartor2(task_id='task_E')
    a >> e
```