# Airflow: How to use the same tasks in different dags

Tags: airflow

I am learning Airflow and run into a problem.

I have 2 tasks, that I want to use in several dags. The difference between these tasks will be only the parameters the operators are going to get.

This could be accomplished by simply copy and pasting the tasks into all the dags, but maintain this type of code would be a nightmare.
So what a want to do is to create a class that will contain the tasks I will be calling several times and just import this class from the dags.

I replicated the issue with a minimal example.

This is the code for the class:

```
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator

class Operator_generator():
    _instance = None
    def __init__(self, var1, var2):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2

    def create_task_1(self):
        return BashOperator(
        task_id='task1',
        bash_command='echo Im running task 1, the current execution date is {{ds}} and the previous execution date is {{prev_ds}}'
    )

    def create_task_2(self):
        return BashOperator(
        task_id='task2',
        bash_command='echo Im running task 2, the current execution date is {{ds}} and the previous execution date is {{prev_ds}}'
    )
```

and this is a dag example where I would import the class

```
from include.src.date.decorator import DefaultDateTime
from airflow import DAG
from include.src.airflow.xcom import cleanup
from operator_creator import Operator_generator

dag_id = "dag1"

default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "start_date": DefaultDateTime(2021, 6, 1),
    'retries': 1
}


# Dag definition
with DAG(
        dag_id,
        schedule_interval='@monthly',
        catchup=False,
        on_failure_callback=cleanup,
        on_success_callback=cleanup
) as dag:
    dag.doc_md = __doc__

    operator_generator = Operator_generator('var1','var2')

    task1 = operator_generator.create_task_1()
    task2 = operator_generator.create_task_2()

    task1 >> task2
```

Note that 'var1' and 'var2' are variables that I need to parametrize the operators.

The problem is that when I run the dag the tasks run twice:

```
[2021-08-25 16:29:46,937] {taskinstance.py:880} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 2
[2021-08-25 16:29:46,937] {taskinstance.py:881} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-08-25 16:29:46,955] {taskinstance.py:900} INFO - Executing <Task(BashOperator): task1> on 2021-07-01T06:00:00+00:00
[2021-08-25 16:29:46,961] {standard_task_runner.py:53} INFO - Started process 67689 to run task
[2021-08-25 16:29:47,011] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - Running %s on host %s <TaskInstance: dag1.task1 2021-07-01T06:00:00+00:00 [running]> 30b770753547
[2021-08-25 16:29:47,032] {bash_operator.py:113} INFO - Tmp dir root location: 
 /tmp
[2021-08-25 16:29:47,033] {bash_operator.py:136} INFO - Temporary script location: /tmp/airflowtmpixijgd4s/task1lfcwdvfa
[2021-08-25 16:29:47,033] {bash_operator.py:146} INFO - Running command: echo Im running task 1, the current execution date is 2021-07-01 and the previous execution date is 2021-06-01
[2021-08-25 16:29:47,039] {bash_operator.py:153} INFO - Output:
[2021-08-25 16:29:47,040] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO - Im running task 1, the current execution date is 2021-07-01 and the previous execution date is 2021-06-01
[2021-08-25 16:29:47,040] {bash_operator.py:161} INFO - Command exited with return code 0
[2021-08-25 16:29:47,052] {taskinstance.py:1065} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS.dag_id=dag1, task_id=task1, execution_date=20210701T060000, start_date=20210825T162946, end_date=20210825T162947
[2021-08-25 16:29:55,335] {taskinstance.py:669} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: dag1.task1 2021-08-25T16:29:41+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-08-25 16:29:55,335] {taskinstance.py:669} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: dag1.task2 2021-07-01T06:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-08-25 16:29:55,348] {taskinstance.py:669} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: dag1.task1 2021-08-25T16:29:41+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-08-25 16:29:55,348] {taskinstance.py:879} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-08-25 16:29:55,348] {taskinstance.py:880} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 2
[2021-08-25 16:29:55,348] {taskinstance.py:881} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-08-25 16:29:55,357] {taskinstance.py:669} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: dag1.task2 2021-07-01T06:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-08-25 16:29:55,357] {taskinstance.py:879} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-08-25 16:29:55,357] {taskinstance.py:880} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 2
[2021-08-25 16:29:55,357] {taskinstance.py:881} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-08-25 16:29:55,363] {taskinstance.py:900} INFO - Executing <Task(BashOperator): task1> on 2021-08-25T16:29:41+00:00
[2021-08-25 16:29:55,366] {standard_task_runner.py:53} INFO - Started process 67809 to run task
[2021-08-25 16:29:55,370] {taskinstance.py:900} INFO - Executing <Task(BashOperator): task2> on 2021-07-01T06:00:00+00:00
[2021-08-25 16:29:55,374] {standard_task_runner.py:53} INFO - Started process 67810 to run task
[2021-08-25 16:29:55,412] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - Running %s on host %s <TaskInstance: dag1.task1 2021-08-25T16:29:41+00:00 [running]> 30b770753547
[2021-08-25 16:29:55,422] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - Running %s on host %s <TaskInstance: dag1.task2 2021-07-01T06:00:00+00:00 [running]> 30b770753547
[2021-08-25 16:29:55,430] {bash_operator.py:113} INFO - Tmp dir root location: 
 /tmp
[2021-08-25 16:29:55,432] {bash_operator.py:136} INFO - Temporary script location: /tmp/airflowtmpsacovlfm/task1doc6fakb
[2021-08-25 16:29:55,432] {bash_operator.py:146} INFO - Running command: echo Im running task 1, the current execution date is 2021-08-25 and the previous execution date is 2021-08-25
[2021-08-25 16:29:55,440] {bash_operator.py:153} INFO - Output:
[2021-08-25 16:29:55,440] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO - Im running task 1, the current execution date is 2021-08-25 and the previous execution date is 2021-08-25
[2021-08-25 16:29:55,441] {bash_operator.py:161} INFO - Command exited with return code 0
[2021-08-25 16:29:55,444] {bash_operator.py:113} INFO - Tmp dir root location: 
 /tmp
[2021-08-25 16:29:55,445] {bash_operator.py:136} INFO - Temporary script location: /tmp/airflowtmpyqqww8an/task2i29a2lk7
[2021-08-25 16:29:55,445] {bash_operator.py:146} INFO - Running command: echo Im running task 2, the current execution date is 2021-07-01 and the previous execution date is 2021-06-01
[2021-08-25 16:29:55,451] {taskinstance.py:1065} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS.dag_id=dag1, task_id=task1, execution_date=20210825T162941, start_date=20210825T162955, end_date=20210825T162955
[2021-08-25 16:29:55,453] {bash_operator.py:153} INFO - Output:
[2021-08-25 16:29:55,453] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO - Im running task 2, the current execution date is 2021-07-01 and the previous execution date is 2021-06-01
[2021-08-25 16:29:55,454] {bash_operator.py:161} INFO - Command exited with return code 0
[2021-08-25 16:29:55,465] {taskinstance.py:1065} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS.dag_id=dag1, task_id=task2, execution_date=20210701T060000, start_date=20210825T162955, end_date=20210825T162955
[2021-08-25 16:29:56,922] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2021-08-25 16:29:56,921] {local_task_job.py:103} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2021-08-25 16:30:05,333] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2021-08-25 16:30:05,333] {local_task_job.py:103} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2021-08-25 16:30:05,337] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2021-08-25 16:30:05,337] {local_task_job.py:103} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2021-08-25 16:30:06,794] {taskinstance.py:669} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: dag1.task2 2021-08-25T16:29:41+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-08-25 16:30:06,809] {taskinstance.py:669} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: dag1.task2 2021-08-25T16:29:41+00:00 [queued]>
[2021-08-25 16:30:06,809] {taskinstance.py:879} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-08-25 16:30:06,810] {taskinstance.py:880} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 2
[2021-08-25 16:30:06,810] {taskinstance.py:881} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-08-25 16:30:06,822] {taskinstance.py:900} INFO - Executing <Task(BashOperator): task2> on 2021-08-25T16:29:41+00:00
[2021-08-25 16:30:06,826] {standard_task_runner.py:53} INFO - Started process 67937 to run task
[2021-08-25 16:30:06,875] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - Running %s on host %s <TaskInstance: dag1.task2 2021-08-25T16:29:41+00:00 [running]> 30b770753547
[2021-08-25 16:30:06,892] {bash_operator.py:113} INFO - Tmp dir root location: 
 /tmp
[2021-08-25 16:30:06,893] {bash_operator.py:136} INFO - Temporary script location: /tmp/airflowtmpot_xsukw/task2xo4uxspu
[2021-08-25 16:30:06,893] {bash_operator.py:146} INFO - Running command: echo Im running task 2, the current execution date is 2021-08-25 and the previous execution date is 2021-08-25
[2021-08-25 16:30:06,901] {bash_operator.py:153} INFO - Output:
[2021-08-25 16:30:06,902] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO - Im running task 2, the current execution date is 2021-08-25 and the previous execution date is 2021-08-25
[2021-08-25 16:30:06,902] {bash_operator.py:161} INFO - Command exited with return code 0
[2021-08-25 16:30:06,913] {taskinstance.py:1065} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS.dag_id=dag1, task_id=task2, execution_date=20210825T162941, start_date=20210825T163006, end_date=20210825T163006
[2021-08-25 16:30:16,800] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2021-08-25 16:30:16,799] {local_task_job.py:103} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
```

Notice how the tasks are executed 2 times:

- In the first execution the values of {{ds}} and {{prev_ds}} are the current date.
- In the second execution the values of {{ds}} and {{prev_ds}} correspond to the monthly interval.

Why the tasks run 2 times?
Is there a way to import tasks like this?

Note 1: I am not allowed to use subdags.

Edit: Adding the execution tree
[image]

Edit 2:
If anyone run into this problem I figured out.

The problem was that I was running the dag with an external trigger, that deletes the dag and start it again. So the the dag runs for the external trigger, but also the scheduler sees that the dag hasn't run for the month, so it schedules the execution, resulting in 2 runs.

The solution I found is:

- Turn off the dag in the airflow interface
- Delete the dag (with the red x in the far right of the dag)
- Refresh the page
- The dag appears again in the list, turn it on

This will make the scheduler do its job and the dag will run as it should.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68921644/how-to-call-a-dag-task/68921824#68921824

Comment: I tried, tasks still run 2 times.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with you using a class to create tasks like that. It works correctly and the dag is executed. It seems that you have unexpected behavior (tasks executed twice) because of the scheduling.

Tasks are executed once with execution date = 2021-07-01, i.e. your start date + 1 month interval and once with execution date = 2021-08-25. Did you trigger a dag manually? How does your execution tree look like in Airflow?

Comment: Yes, I triggered the dag manually. Also, I edited the question to add the view of the execution tree